# Local storage and ngrxstore

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage, ngrx

I have an angular2app. I stored my data into localstorage. Every time when the action getting chage local storage data will clear. How can i store this localstorage data into ngrxstore. I have the following:

component.ts

```
onClickRoom(room: string): void {
this.date = new Date();
this.evntList = new events('', '', '');
this.evntList.timestamp = this.date;
this.evntList.name = room;
this.evntList.type = this.type;
console.log("eventList:", this.evntList);
this.eventArray.push(this.evntList);
this.tokenmanager.store(this.eventArray);
console.log('Room clicked: ', this.eventArray); ---> This event array successfully updating.
}
```

globalstorage.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenManager {

public tokenKey: string = 'app_token';

constructor() { }

store(content) {

    localStorage.setItem(this.tokenKey, JSON.stringify(content));

}

retrieve() {
    let storedToken: any = localStorage.getItem(this.tokenKey);


    if (!storedToken) throw 'no token found';
    return storedToken;
}
}
```

My view is:

- abc
- pqr    -----> This is a list.
- qwe

While I'm clicking abc 3 things get stored into local storage like:

```
[{name: "abc", timestamp:time, type: "typename"}].
```

then after i clik the array will get update into

```
[{name: "abc", timestamp:time, type: "typename"}, {name: "pqr", timestamp:time, type: "typename"}].
```

But after refreshing the page and click the same item the previously stored data will lost and array is updated with new value. But actually what I need is a new appended array. Which means previously stored data and newly stored data. How can I  implement this?

How can i store this local storage data to ngrx store for getting all evnts. I'm new to angular2 and ngrx store. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is already a quite old question, but just stumbled upon this one and am working on something similar.

I am using ngrx-store-localstorage, this module is automatically synchronizing a ngrx-store with the localstorage if you are using the rehydrate option.

Hope that helps anybody stumbling upon this problem.